# How can I login to a website that is not owned by me through an Android App?

Tags: android, web, authentication, response, external

I would like to know how I can manage to login into a website (www.garena.com) which is not mine, and neither do I know what kind of response it sends through MY own Android app.
I've searched for a while but could not find something that matches what I need to do. Is it possible? And if yes, then HOW?

Comment: what do you want just clarify or post some code.

Comment: I basically need to login to http://www.garena.com through a native android application and then display stuff from the actual portal into my native app.

Comment: why dont you go for WebView and load the url in it ??

Comment: Because I want to have an standalone native app for it.

Answer (score 0):

You could find out whether the website has some API's that allow you to login, that should be the best solution. If there isn't any API available you could try to fill the login fields programmatically.

Comment: I've already thought over that option of logging in programatically..
But since I want to use some content later, logging in that way is of no use.
And no, the website does not have any APIs.